# reqAllOpenOrders() not able to download data of my account

Tags: tws, ib-api

I am new to ibapi and using liberary "https://pypi.org/project/ibapi/".
I want to download all the details of orders inside red box in image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5fQK.png)

Code is

```
from ibapi.client import EClient 
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper 
from ibapi.contract import Contract 

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self) 

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        print("contractDetails: ", reqId, " ", contractDetails) 

    def openOrder(self):
        super().openOrder()
        print("OpenOrder. PermId: ", order.permId, "ClientId:", order.clientId, " OrderId:", orderId, "Account:", order.account, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:", contract.secType,"Exchange:", contract.exchange, "Action:", order.action, "OrderType:", order.orderType,"TotalQty:", order.totalQuantity, "CashQty:", order.cashQty, "LmtPrice:", order.lmtPrice, "AuxPrice:", order.auxPrice, "Status:", orderState.status)
        order.contract = contract
        self.permId2ord[order.permId] = order



def main():
    app = TestApp() 
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 1111, 0)
    app.reqAllOpenOrders()
    app.run() 
    app.disconnect()


main()
```

kindly help me to find out the mistake or share some completely different approach if you have.

Comment: please reformat your text so its readable. The formatting of the code is messed up.

Comment: I have edited the code...sorry this was my first time with code on stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of the openOrder function are incorrect so its likely not overriding the EWrapper function and ever receiving a callback. It should be:

```
 def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
```

(If `openOrder(self)` in your example were ever called it would throw an error because `order.contract` is undefined)

Other problems:

- There should be a pause between connecting and calling any other functions in EClient (its best to wait for the nextValidID callback)
- The run() loop is infinite so the disconnect() in your program will never be called.

You would probably be interested in the Python API course in the [Trader's Academy](https://www.ibkr.com/en/index.php?f=45473&cat=none) on the IBKR website.